# Closing a shape in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I created a shape (not a path) in PS, but forgot to close the shape by clicking on the first point after drawing it with the pen tool.  How do I close the shape after I've moved on and forgot?  It looks fine without closing it, but I can't create new points on the last line segment since it was never closed.

Answer (score 5):

Most importantly take Pen Tool and make sure you have **Auto Add/Delete** selected.

[image]

After that hold down Ctrl+Alt buttons to temporarily activate Path Selection Tool and click your *Shape* to select it.

Then just click to one of the points that isn't closed and then click to the next point to close the path.

---

---

Symbol for point that isn't closed.

[image]

After clicking point that isn't closed, hovering over another similar point will show this symbol.

[image]

Comment: I have followed your directions to the letter and can't get this to work and it's driving me mad.  I never get the Symbols when I hover over the unconnected points.  I am on CS3 on a Mac if that matters.

Comment: @RogerGilbrat I tried every scenario I could think of and I had no problems connecting the points (Mac PS cs3) I would like to know what kind of symbol it shows when you hover over point that isn't closed?

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this silly little question myself, I figured I try and help the next person. I ran into this problem by using custom shapes, then deleting parts that I didn't want/need. This would leave me with an unclosed shape that does odd things when manipulating.

To resolve, use the direct selection tool and click and drag over both shapes/paths that are not closed, highlighting/selecting both shapes/paths. Next, hit U on the keyboard to bring up Shape/Path toolbar. Click on the Path Operations icon (the little double square icon) and select the bottom choice, Merge Shape Components.

Six years tardy to the OP, but hopefully helps somebody down the line.