# Path Fill Not filling up Selected Space Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, cs6, path

I'm new to photoshop. This is my first time using the pen tool to draw the path below, but when I use paint bucket it's not filling up the spaces inside the path I have drawn. It fills up some space outside the path. Please help. I'm desperate. I want to make this right.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer for this question. For your problem I used both illustrator and photoshop to solve this issue. First i created the shape in illustrator using the path tool. Once you create the whole shape then you select all the shape and divide them using the divide path from path finder. Then i copied all the shape in phothsop.

When I copy the shape in photoshop i selected path. Then you can select the parts of the shape using direct path selection tool and then you can separate them by cutting the shape to a new shape layer. You can do it from layer menu. Layer>New>Shape Layers via cut. Then you will see new shape layer has been created in layer panel and then you can easily fill the shape with new color.

Please see the screen capture below.

[image]

Comment: that's a complicated way of solving this! You can do it all in Photoshop with just the path tool, if the shape is not too complex (like the one in the question).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple: your path is open. As such, photoshop will try to fill all the concave spaces. Make it a closed path (where start and ending point are the same) using the pen tool and it will be filled correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. I'd like to try using Illustrator however I only have Photoshop at this time. I'd probably try it at a later time after this has been resolved. Provided that my path is indeed open, how do I close the paths? My problem is that I don't know how to close them because I can't seem to find any gaps no matter how I zoom in on the shape, it's showing that the lines have intersecting points. Can you enlighten how to go about this predicament?

Comment: take a look at this answer http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/closing-a-shape-in-photoshop

Comment: hey Foximile did you solve your issue with path fill on Photoshop? Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct.